# Can you explain with example the use of CONSTRAINT keyword in for foreign keys Mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT
```

I am unable to understand this syntax from Mysql documentation on the use of the constraint keyword especially the part in line 2 `([index_name])`

Comment: Do you use NDB tables?

Comment: Msql documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) explains each section in a detailed manner and ptovides examples. Can you pls be more specific as to what you are confused about? Pls ptovide an example!

Comment: `In syntax descriptions, square brackets (“[” and “]”) indicate optional words or clauses.` ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/manual-info.html))

Comment: @Shadow I don't exactly understand why do we use the constraint keyword. I mean why do we use it? How does it helps us?

Comment: It is an optional part of the syntax, you can leave it out, if you want to.